# angularjs currency converter

Tags: angularjs, converters

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to build simple currency converter app. It has 2 drop-downs, 'From' currency and 'To' currency. 'To' currency has only 1 option as of now: INR. I am trying to display result of conversion in alert box, for given amount and exchange rates are hard coded. Code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Enter amount: <input type="text" ng-model="amount">
Select 'From' currency:
<select ng-model="myVar">
<option value="usd">USD
<option value="eur">Euro
<option value="gbp">GBP
</select>
Select 'To' currency:
<select ng-model="myVar2">
<option value="inr">INR
</select>
<button ng-click="convert()">Convert</button>
<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.SwitchFunction = function(myVar){
switch(myVar){
case 'usd': alert($scope.amount + " USD equals" + $scope.amount*70 + "INR");
case 'eur': alert($scope.amount + " EUR equals" + $scope.amount*60 + "INR");
case 'gbp': alert($scope.amount + " GBP equals" + $scope.amount*80 + "INR");

}
};
});
</script>
```

Q: I cannot bind user-input to drop-down. 
Q: I want to trigger generate() on ng-click. Can I do that along with switch.

Most help I read about switch focuses mostly on display and not on calculation part i.e. exchange rate :(

Answer (score 1):

To bind user-input you need to create a variable in your controller to bind to. This you do by defining `$scope.myVariable = "Something"`, for example. You can also do this to make objects and arrays by adding, for example `$scope.myArray = ["A", "B"]` or `$scope.myObject = {}`.

Q1: **If you create an array with, for example, countrycodes, you can loop through that array using ng-repeat.** This you can use to bind and expand your list of options in the selector. Adding a new item to the array will automatically add it to the ng-repeat, so it will instantly be a new option for your user.

Q2: **If you want to trigger the alerts on your button, you need to actually add the function to your scope by using `$scope.generate = function() { }`.** Then, by adding `ng-click="generate()` to your button, you can trigger it. See the added snippet below for an example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.toCurrencyList = [{
    code: "inr"
  }]
  $scope.fromCurrencyList = [];
  $scope.fromCurrencyList.push({
    code: "usd",
    value: 70
  });
  $scope.fromCurrencyList.push({
    code: "eur",
    value: 60
  });
  $scope.fromCurrencyList.push({
    code: "gbp",
    value: 80
  });
  
  $scope.myVar = "usd";
  $scope.myVar2 = "inr";
  $scope.newFromCurrency = "";
  $scope.newValue = "";
  $scope.output = "";
  
  $scope.convert = function() {
    for (var currencyIndex in $scope.fromCurrencyList) {
      if ($scope.myVar == $scope.fromCurrencyList[currencyIndex].code) {
        $scope.output = $scope.amount + "" + $scope.fromCurrencyList[currencyIndex].code + " equals " + $scope.amount * $scope.fromCurrencyList[currencyIndex].value + "" + $scope.myVar2;
        alert($scope.output);
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.addFromCurrency = function() {
    var newFromCurrency = {};
    newFromCurrency.code = $scope.newCurrency;
    newFromCurrency.value = $scope.newValue;
    $scope.fromCurrencyList.push(newFromCurrency)
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <label>Enter amount:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="amount" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Select 'From' currency:
    <select ng-model="myVar">
      <option ng-repeat="fromCurrency in fromCurrencyList" value="{{fromCurrency.code}}">
        {{fromCurrency.code}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Select 'To' currency:
    <select ng-model="myVar2">
      <option ng-repeat="toCurrency in toCurrencyList" value="{{toCurrency.code}}">
        {{toCurrency.code}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="convert()">Convert</button>
    {{output}}
  </div>

  <hr />

  <div>
    <input ng-model="newCurrency" placeholder="newCurrency" />
    <input ng-model="newValue" placeholder="newValue" />
    <button ng-click="addFromCurrency()">Add to Currency List</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The for-loop in the controller shows you how to handle input from users in a more flexible way than your switch statement. You can look at the code I used to add "From"-currency and replicate that for the "To"-currency. (Try, for example, inputting the values 'Something' and '100' in the input fields.)